# Query runs on DB but throws exception in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, subquery

I'm having some trouble executing a nested sql query. It works fine when i run it on TOAD (for Oracle DB) but when I try and execute the same query from my java program it gives me an error : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected:
Here is the query:

```
Select *
from(select tb1.Number, tb1.Desc, tb1.Local, tb2.Division
     from tb1
     inner join tb2
     on tb1.Number = tb2.Number
     and Local in ('ENG_USA', 'ENG_CHINA', 'FR_FRENCH'))
where Number in ('7512','4706')
```

Like I mentioned, it executes fine on Toad and is able to retrieve data but the same query throws the ORA-00923 exception.

```
rset = stmt.executeQuery(Select *
from(select tb1.Number, tb1.Desc, tb1.Local, tb2.Division
from tb1
inner join tb2
on tb1.Number = tb2.Number
and Local in ("+loc+"))
where Number in ("+s+")
```

Reply With Quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with mysql. My problem was that i splitted the query in multiple rows without leaving a space between 2 rows.
So your query should be:

```
rset = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from(select tb1.Number, tb1.Desc, tb1.Local, tb2.Division from tb1 inner join tb2 on tb1.Number = tb2.Number and Local in ("+loc+")) where Number in ("+s+")"
```

PS: I would like to write this as a comment but for some reason i can't in this question. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't see the beginning or ending double-quotes in your Java code.  Since your Java code must compile in order to get far enough to receive an Oracle error, I'm assuming that there is a double quote prior to the `SELECT`, a double-quote after the final close paren, and then another close parent to match to the open paren on the `executeQuery`.  So I'm assuming that your actual code is something like

```
rset = stmt.executeQuery(
        "Select *
           from(select tb1.Number, tb1.Desc, tb1.Local, tb2.Division
                  from tb1
                       inner join tb2
                          on tb1.Number = tb2.Number
                             and Local in ("+loc+"))
                 where Number in ("+s+")");
```

Is there a reason that you're building the SQL statement dynamically rather than using bind variables?  Using bind variables is more secure since you don't need to worry about SQL injection attacks.  It is more efficient since you're not forcing the database to hard parse the query every time.  And it saves you from many sorts of errors around quoting and escaping.  In your case, assuming that the local variable `loc` does not have the leading and trailing single quotes, you'd need to include those in your query

```
rset = stmt.executeQuery(
        "Select *
           from(select tb1.Number, tb1.Desc, tb1.Local, tb2.Division
                  from tb1
                       inner join tb2
                          on tb1.Number = tb2.Number
                             and Local in ('"+loc+"'))
                 where Number in ("+s+")");
```

Had you used bind variables and just bound `loc` to the first bind variable, on the other hand, you wouldn't need to worry about adding the single quotes (or escaping any single quotes in `loc`.

Comment: the string loc is already appended with single quotes,something like this:
    String loc = "'ENG_USA','ENG_CHINA', 'FR_FRANCE'";
As for the double quotes, I'm sorry it was a typo. I've them in my code..so this still would give me the same error.

Comment: @user973536 - Can you build the SQL statement in a string variable, print that variable, and then pass that variable to the `executeQuery` call?  You're introducing an error at some point in building up the SQL statement but it's hard to tell for sure where the error is happening without knowing exactly what is in both variables.  Of course, it would be easier if you were using bind variables so you didn't have to worry about those things.

Comment: I pass the query in a single row and it worked. So I suppose breaking up the query into multiple rows had some kind of an issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If multiline statements throw an error it's almost always a problem with missing whitespace at the end of the line. If you add a blank before the `"` at the end you should be fine: `"SELECT col" + "FROM some_table"` will produce invalid SQL. "`SELECT col " + "FROM some_table"` will create valid SQL. If you follow that rule, multiline statements are not a problem.